# Prove that the three statements are equivalent

Tags: discrete-mathematics, self-learning

I need to show that the following statements are equivalent.

A $\subset$ B, A $\cap$ B$^c$ = $\emptyset$, and A$^c \cup$ B = U (U is the universal set)

So to show that A $\subset$ B is true I said if x$\in$A and and if x$\in$B, then A $\subset$ B is true.

For A $\cap$ B$^c$ = $\emptyset$, I said, if x$\in$A and x$\notin$B, then the intersection is empty so this is true.

I am interpreting the previous statement as, x is an element in A and x is not an element in B therefore, the intersection of A and B is empty. Is that correct?

If I am reading this properly, I cannot see how A $\subset$ B implies A $\cap$ B$^c$ = $\emptyset$, and this is what I need help with.

Thanks,

Tony

Comment: Note: for the second part, you mean to show that x is not in the complement, rather than $B$ (recall $B^c$ is defined as $U/B$)
If x is not in $B$, x is in the complement and thus the intersection is *not* empty.  Do you see why?

Comment: So far, I have: If x$\in$A then by definition of \subset, x$\in$B. If x$\in$B$^c$, then A$\cap$B$^c$ = $\emptyset$ is true. However, we know that x$\in$B, and if x$\in$B$^c$ then A$\cap$B$^c$ = $\emptyset$ is true. However, we know that x$\in$B therefore, x$\notin$B$^c$, thus A$\cap$B $\neq \emptyset$. Likewise, if x$\in$A$^c$, then A$^c\cup$B = U is true. But, x$\in$A and therefore A$^c\cup$B = U is false.

Comment: Your second sentence is redundant.
But you have that direction correct - depending on your professor, they may want you to add that "and  the fact that $A\cap B^c = \emptyset$ follows from this."
However, the second part isn't right; $A^c\cup B = U$ is always true. Why? Remember that $A \subset B$.  In that case, what is $A^c = U/A$?

Also, don't forget that when you're proving equality, you want to prove both directions.

Comment: The symbol / is not used in my book. Does it mean the same as U - A? I believe A$^c$ $\cup$ = $U$ is always true because A$^c$ is everything not in A and in this case that include everything in B and $U$, and $U$ includes all elements. Is that correct? To show that A $\cap$ B$^c$ = $\emptyset$ implies A$^c$ $\cup$ = $U$, I used De Morgans Laws. Now I need to show why A$^c$ $\cup$ = $U$ implies A $\subset$ B.

Answer (score 0):

You want to show that A ⊂ B implies  A ∩ (B complement) = ∅ and vice versa.

Suppose that A ⊂ B. This means that for all a in A we have that a is in B. So is it possible for there to be an a' in A that is not in B?

If it is not possible then we have shown that none of the a's in A are in B complement. So what does that mean about their intersection.

Think about it.

Answer (score 0):

We are given three statements:
$$
\begin{align}
\text{(a) }&A \subset B\\
\text{(b) }&A \cap B^c = \phi\\
\text{(c) }&A^c \cup B = U
\end{align}
$$
To prove that the three statements are equivalent we show that $\text{(a)}\implies \text{(b)},\text{(b)}\implies\text{(c)},\text{ and }\text{(c)}\implies \text{(a)}$

1. prove $\text{(a)}\implies \text{(b)}$:
   $$
   \begin{align}
   & A \subset B\\
   \implies & x\in B\ \forall x \in A \\
   \implies & \{x: x\in A, x \notin B \} = \phi\\
   \implies & A \cap B^c = \phi
   \end{align}
   $$
2. prove $\text{(b)}\implies \text{(c)}$:
   $$
   \begin{align}
   &A\cap B^c = \phi\\
   \implies &\left(A \cap B^c\right)^c = \phi^c\\
   \implies &A^c\cup B = U
   \end{align}
   $$
3. prove $\text{(c)}\implies \text{(a)}$:
   $$
   \begin{align}
   &A^c\cup B = U\\
   \implies &\{x:x \notin A\text{ or }x\in B\} = U\\
   \implies &\{x:x \in A \text{ and } x\notin B\} = \phi\\
   \implies &x\in B\ \forall x \in A \\
   \implies &A \subset B
   \end{align}
   $$

Hence the equivalence of the three statements is proved.